# Adding the values in a python list in between two dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, sum

I have list of integers. In that list there are two dictionaries like so:

```
value_list = [1180, 1190, 1190, {'low': 1180}, 1130, 1130, 1180, {'low':1160}, 1130]
```

The output I am trying to get is the sum of the values in between the two dictionaries, as well as the values of the dictionaries. For example:

```
for item in value_list:
     # if item in list is a dict, sum its value
     # with value of next dict and values in between
```

In this case the output would be `5780`

One method I thought of is finding the index number of the two dicts and using them like this:

```
value_list[3]['low'] + sum(value_list[4:7]) + value_list[7]['low']
```

But that seems way too convoluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code, assuming the only types you have are int and dict, and the dict will always have the same format:

```
total_sum = 0
dicts_num = 0 #flag for checking how many dicts have appeared  
for value in value_list:
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        dicts_num += 1
        total_sum += value["low"]
    elif (dicts_num == 1):
        total_sum += value
```

Comment: This worked for me! I only have to worry about integers in this list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop with a flag variable

```
found_dict = False
total = 0
for i in value_list:
    if found_dict:
        if type(i) is dict:
            total += i['low']
            break
        else:
            total += i
    elif type(i) is dict:
        total += i['low']
        found_dict = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only numeric values between the first and last dicts in the `value_list`:

```
value_list = [1180, 1190, 1190, {'low': 1180}, 1130, 1130, 1180, {'low':1160}, 1130]
dicts = [(i, list(d.values())[0]) for i, d in enumerate(value_list) if isinstance(d, dict)]
sum(value_list[dicts[0][0] + 1 : dicts[-1][0]]) + sum(t[-1] for t in dicts)
# Outputs: 5780
```

If the assumption is not correct this needs to be more complex.

Comment: hmm, getting invalid syntax, it points at the `for` in the `dicts` variable, running python 3.x

Comment: @louielouielouie Ah, sorry, copy-paste error, I fixed the syntax, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the indices (indexes?) of the dict objects, you can use them in a list comprehension:

`sum([x if type(x)==int else x['low'] for x in value_list[3:8]])`

Answer (score 0):

Quick and lazy solution, although I'm sure I'll catch some flak for not catching and handling exceptions properly

```
fl = 0
s = 0
for i in value_list:
    if fl == 0:
        if type(i) == dict:
             s += i['low']
             fl = 1
             continue
    if fl == 1:
        try:
            s += i
        except:
            s += i['low']
            fl = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the indices of the dicts and use a function to extract value if needed

```
def int_or_value(item, key='low'):
    if isinstance(item, int):
        return item
    else:
        return item[key]

value_list = [1180, 1190, 1190, {'low': 1180}, 1130, 1130, 1180, {'low':1160}, 1130]
indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(value_list) if isinstance(value, dict)]

# Use this if you have multiple instances of {dict} ... {dict} to sum in you value_list
for start, stop in (indices[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(indices), 2)):
    print(sum(int_or_value(item) for item in value_list[start:stop+1]))

# If you are sure there is going to be a single instance of {dict} ... {dict} to sum just access indices directly
print(sum(int_or_value(item) fro item in value_list[indices[0]:indices[1]+1]))
```